# Does using UX.SE on a mobile device count towards consecutive days?

Tags: discussion

For the last two days, I've been accessing UX.SE using the SixToEight iPhone App.  Not just logging in, but reading questions, checking answers etc.

I now checked my consecutive days, and it seems that the system thinks I haven't been on at all for the last two days.

Is this a bug, or does use from a mobile application not count for consecutive days?

Comment: This isn't a mobile question but an app one.  I use the browser on my mobile phone to access SE sites and it notices that.

Answer (score 5):

How would the site even know that it's you? As far as I see it, SixToEight (which, by the way, is not an official app, which kinda makes this an off-topic question) uses the API, which currently doesn't support authentication.